# AutoScroll scrollbar hides part of my control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a control in C# that I want to AutoScroll. But when the scroll bar appears, it overlays part of the control. Is there any way I can make the control resize its contents to accomodate the scroll bar? This isn't a custom control; it's a standard .NET TabPage control. I *really* don't want to have to wire up a scroll bar manually...

Comment: If you don't want to hide part of your control when the scrollbar is displayed, the only solution is change (enlarge) your control accordingly. I think that's even a worse effect. You still want that?

Comment: Yeah, that would definitely be worse.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by adding a Panel control to the control I wanted to scroll, with a 12px right margin to accommodate the scrollbar. Not sure how this will look on high DPI settings, but it can always be tweaked.